# Userform Excel: finding the order of the code(buttons etc), inorder to change, so the user can press 'tab' on form and it will move to the next one

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fix the order of the cursor when the user presses 'tab' to go in order. Not sure where the order is, i've tried moving around everything in the VBA

Comment: its the TabIndex property for control. Also, in the View Menu--Tab Order item allows you to manage tabs for all the controls on a user form.

Comment: @cyboashu Excellent tip with the view>tab order, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object on the Userform has a TabIndex property, adjust the numbering for each object to adjust the order.

Comment: You're the best!!! I thought that had meant to bring back or forward an object. WOW THANK YOU